# Terraform multple For loops

Tags: terraform

I have  a YAML file as follows

```
applications:
  - name: SSbasic
    rule_type: Basic
    backend:
      - name: T1
        port: 443
        names:
          - ss-app.apps.rnd.ecp.az.nodomain.com
        root_certs:
          - pgsdroot-ca
  - name: SSRouting
    rule_type: PathBasedRouting
    backend:
      - name: SS-Backend01
        port: 443
        names:
          - testiq-app.apps.rnd.ecp.az.nodomain.com
        root_certs: -droot-ca
        path:
          - /pensionValuation/
      - name: SS-Backend02
        port: 443
        names:
          - testiq-app.apps.rnd.ecp.az.nodomain.com
        root_certs:
          - droot-ca
        path:
          - /pb/test2
```

In local.tf,   i need to read the values  in  the above yaml values like backend.port , backend.root_certs

local.tf

```
locals {
  # Parse the application_data (YAML) in Terraform object
   applications_yaml = yamldecode(file(var.application_data))

  backend_http_settings = { for i in local.applications_yaml.applications : [
    for j in i.backend : {
      ruletype=  i.rule_type
      port  = j.port
      rootcert = j. root_certs
  } ] 
}
}
```

I'm very new to terraform .Can you please advise  what I'm doing  wrong in the terraform for  loop  ? what is the right  way to get the correct values ?

Comment: "I'm doing wrong in the terraform for loop" - you haven't even explained what's wrong with your loop. Any errors?

Comment: Error: Invalid 'for' expression
│ 
│ On locals.tf

Comment: You either don't have the correct closing curly bracket or you didn't copy and paste everything properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `{ }` in your first loop, which is producing an object that expects an expression of type `key => value`, so an expression like:

```
backend_http_settings = { for i in local.applications_yaml.applications : i.name => [
    for j in i.backend : {
    ruletype = i.rule_type
    port     = j.port
    rootcert = j.root_certs
    }]
}
```

Would produce a plan like the following:

```
  + file = {
      + SSRouting = [
          + {
              + port     = 443
              + rootcert = "-droot-ca"
              + ruletype = "PathBasedRouting"
            },
          + {
              + port     = 443
              + rootcert = [
                  + "droot-ca",
                ]
              + ruletype = "PathBasedRouting"
            },
        ]
      + SSbasic   = [
          + {
              + port     = 443
              + rootcert = [
                  + "pgsdroot-ca",
                ]
              + ruletype = "Basic"
            },
        ]
    }
```

---

In case you want to produce an tuple, use `[]`

```
backend_http_settings = [
    for i in local.applications_yaml.applications : [
        for j in i.backend : {
        ruletype = i.rule_type
        port     = j.port
        rootcert = j.root_certs
    }]
]
```

Which produces an output like the following:

```
  + file = [
      + [
          + {
              + port     = 443
              + rootcert = [
                  + "pgsdroot-ca",
                ]
              + ruletype = "Basic"
            },
        ],
      + [
          + {
              + port     = 443
              + rootcert = "-droot-ca"
              + ruletype = "PathBasedRouting"
            },
          + {
              + port     = 443
              + rootcert = [
                  + "droot-ca",
                ]
              + ruletype = "PathBasedRouting"
            },
        ],
    ]
```

And if you want to flatten that output you can use [`flatten()`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/flatten)

```
backend_http_settings = flatten([
    for i in local.applications_yaml.applications : [
        for j in i.backend : {
        ruletype = i.rule_type
        port     = j.port
        rootcert = j.root_certs
    }]
])
```

Plan:

```
  + file = [
      + {
          + port     = 443
          + rootcert = [
              + "pgsdroot-ca",
            ]
          + ruletype = "Basic"
        },
      + {
          + port     = 443
          + rootcert = "-droot-ca"
          + ruletype = "PathBasedRouting"
        },
      + {
          + port     = 443
          + rootcert = [
              + "droot-ca",
            ]
          + ruletype = "PathBasedRouting"
        },
    ]
```

Read more:

- For loop results: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/for#result-types
- Functions (in case you want to convert output types): https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions